# Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError bad response Unauthorized 401 sidekiqpro github actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github-actions, sidekick

Hi every one I have a problem when I executed my ci with github actions I received this problem.

```
Retrying download gem from https://gems.contribsys.com/ due to error (2/4): Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError bad response Unauthorized 401
```

this is my .yml file to github actions

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:13-alpine
        ports:
          - "5432:5432"
        options:
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5  
        env:
          POSTGRES_DB: rails_test
    env:
      RAILS_ENV: test
      DATABASE_URL: "postgres://rails:password@localhost:5432/rails_test"
      SIDEKIQ_PRO_USER: ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PRO_USER }}
      SIDEKIQ_PRO_PWD:  ${{ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PRO_PWD }}


  lint:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Ruby and gems
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@8f312efe1262fb463d906e9bf040319394c18d3e # v1.92
        with:
          bundler-cache: true
      # Add or replace any other lints here
      - name: Security audit dependencies
        run: bin/bundler-audit --update |
          bundle config gems.contribsys.com ${secrets.SIDEKIQ_PRO_USER}:${ secrets.SIDEKIQ_PRO_PWD }
      - name: Security audit application code
        run: bin/brakeman -q -w2
      - name: Lint Ruby files
        run: bin/rubocop --parallel
```

in my gemfile I put this

```
gem 'sidekiq-pro', '~> 5.3', source: 'https://gems.contribsys.com'
```

For other hands, how I can print my ENV in console of github actions , I am not sure if the variable that I set is filled , any ideas?

Comment: DId you figure this out?